# how to hide and show div with javascript after options been selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So i've been trying to create an cost estimation form for my website project. The whole idea is I'll prepare about 10 questions, and the website will be only showing the next question after the client answered the first previous ones.

It works fine until when the options were provided in `select` instead of `radio`. It won't show the next question even client has answered the previous ones.

I'm not too sure what I did wrong and hope peeps here can give me a direction.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#problem").hide();
  $("#brand").hide();
  $("#ipmodel").hide();
  $("#stype").hide();
  $("#sgsmodel").hide();
  $("#sgnmodel").hide();
  $("#nmodel").hide();
  $("#smodel").hide();
  $("#turnon").hide();
  $("#liquiddamage").hide();
  $("#result").hide();
  var input = document.getElementById('phone');

  document.getElementById('phone_no').addEventListener('click', function() {
    showBrand();
    hideProblem();
    hideIpmodel();
    hideStype();
    hideSgsmodel();
    hideSgnmodel();
    hideNmodel();
    hideSmodel();
    hideTurnon();
    hideLiquiddamage();
  });

  document.getElementById('phone_yes').addEventListener('click', function() {
    showBrand();
    hideProblem();
    hideIpmodel();
    hideStype();
    hideSgsmodel();
    hideSgnmodel();
    hideNmodel();
    hideSmodel();
    hideTurnon();
    hideLiquiddamage();
  });

  document.getElementById('applephone').addEventListener('click', function() {
    showBrand();
    hideProblem();
    showIpmodel();
    hideStype();
    hideSgsmodel();
    hideSgnmodel();
    hideNmodel();
    hideSmodel();
    hideTurnon();
    hideLiquiddamage();
  });
  
  document.getElementById('gss').addEventListener('click', function() {
    showBrand();
    hideProblem();
    hideIpmodel();
    showStype();
    showSgsmodel();
    hideSgnmodel();
    hideNmodel();
    hideSmodel();
    hideTurnon();
    hideLiquiddamage();
  });
  
  
  document.getElementById('samsungphone').addEventListener('click', function() {
    showBrand();
    hideProblem();
    hideIpmodel();
    showStype();
    hideSgsmodel();
    hideSgnmodel();
    hideNmodel();
    hideSmodel();
    hideTurnon();
    hideLiquiddamage();
  });
  
  
  document.getElementById('gns').addEventListener('click', function() {
    showBrand();
    hideProblem();
    hideIpmodel();
    showStype();
    hideSgsmodel();
    showSgnmodel();
    hideNmodel();
    hideSmodel();
    hideTurnon();
    hideLiquiddamage();
  });
  
  document.getElementById('nokiaphone').addEventListener('click', function() {
    showBrand();
    hideProblem();
    hideIpmodel();
    hideStype();
    hideSgsmodel();
    hideSgnmodel();
    showNmodel();
    hideSmodel();
    hideTurnon();
    hideLiquiddamage();
  });
  
  document.getElementById('sonyphone').addEventListener('click', function() {
    showBrand();
    hideProblem();
    hideIpmodel();
    hideStype();
    hideSgsmodel();
    hideSgnmodel();
    hideNmodel();
    showSmodel();
    hideTurnon();
    hideLiquiddamage();
  });
  
  document.getElementById('otherphone').addEventListener('click', function() {
    showBrand();
    hideProblem();
    hideIpmodel();
    hideStype();
    hideSgsmodel();
    hideSgnmodel();
    hideNmodel();
    hideSmodel();
    hideTurnon();
    hideLiquiddamage();
  });

  function showProblem() {
    $("#problem").show();
  }

  function hideProblem() {
    $("#problem").hide();
  }

  function showBrand() {
    $("#brand").show();
  }

  function hideBrand() {
    $("#brand").hide();
  }

  function showIpmodel() {
    $("#ipmodel").show();
  }

  function hideIpmodel() {
    $("#ipmodel").hide();
  }

  function showStype() {
    $("#stype").show();
  }

  function hideStype() {
    $("#stype").hide();
  }

  function showSgsmodel() {
    $("#sgsmodel").show();
  }

  function hideSgsmodel() {
    $("#sgsmodel").hide();
  }
  
  function showSgnmodel() {
    $("#sgnmodel").show();
  }

  function hideSgnmodel() {
    $("#sgnmodel").hide();
  }

  function showNmodel() {
    $("#nmodel").show();
  }

  function hideNmodel() {
    $("#nmodel").hide();
  }

  function showSmodel() {
    $("#smodel").show();
  }

  function hideSmodel() {
    $("#smodel").hide();
  }

  function showTurnon() {
    $("#turnon").show();
  }

  function hideTurnon() {
    $("#turnon").hide();
  }

  function showLiquiddamage() {
    $("#liquiddamage").show();
  }

  function hideLiquiddamage() {
    $("#liquiddamage").hide();
  }

  function showResult() {
    $("#result").show();
  }

  function hideResult() {
    $("#result").hide();
  }


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="tabletmobilerepairform">
  <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 nopad" id="create">
    <div class="form-group text-center">
      <b>Is it a tablet or a phone?</b><br />
      <div class="radio" id="phone">
        <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="phone" id="phone_yes" value="1">
                        It's a tablet.
                    </label>

      </div>
      <div class="radio">
        <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="phone" id="phone_no" value="0">
                        It's a phone.
                    </label>
      </div>
    </div><br/> <!-- tablets or phones --> 
    <div class="form-group" id="brand">
     <b>What is the brand of your phone?</b><br />
                <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="brand" id="applephone" value="b1">
                        Apple
                    </label><br/>
                <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="brand" id="samsungphone" value="b2">
                        Samsung
                    </label><br/>
                <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="brand" id="nokiaphone" value="b3">
                        Nokia
                    </label><br/>
                <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="brand" id="sonyphone" value="b4">
                        Sony
                    </label><br/>
                <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="brand" id="otherphone" value="b5">
                        Other
                    </label>
                   
    </div><br/>  <!-- Which brand of phones --> 
            <div class="form-group" id="ipmodel">
                <b>What is the model of your phone?</b><br />
                <select class="form-control" name="ipmodel" id="ipmodel">
                    <option value="i1" id="ip5">iPhone 5</option>
                    <option value="i2" id="ip5c">iPhone 5c</option>
                    <option value="i3" id="ip5s">iPhone 5s</option>
                    <option value="i4" id="ip6">iPhone 6</option>
                    <option value="i5" id="ip6p">iPhone 6 Plus</option>
                    <option value="i6" id="ipse">iPhone SE</option>
                    <option value="i7" id="ip6s">iPhone 6s</option>
                    <option value="i8" id="ip6sp">iPhone 6s Plus</option>
                    <option value="i9" id="ip7">iPhone 7</option>
                    <option value="i10" id="ip7p">iPhone 7 Plus</option>
                    <option value="i11" id="ip8">iPhone 8</option>
                    <option value="i12" id="ip8p">iPhone 8 Plus</option>
                    <option value="i13" id="ipx">iPhone X</option>
                    <option value="i14" id="ipo">Other</option>                   
                </select>
            </div><br/> <!-- Apple phones -->  
    <div class="form-group" id="stype">
                <b>Is it a Samsung Galaxy S series or Galaxy Note series phone?</b><br />

      <select class="form-control" name="stype" id="stype">
                    <option value="st1" id="gss">Galaxy S series</option>
                    <option value="st2" id="gns">Galaxy Note series</option>
                    <option value="st3" id="go">Other</option>
                </select>
    </div><br/> <!-- Samsung what phones -->  
                <div class="form-group" id="sgsmodel">
                <b>What is the model of your phone?</b><br />
                <select class="form-control" name="sgsmodel" id="sgsmodel">">
                    <option value="g1" id="gs4">Galaxy s4</option>
                    <option value="g2" id="gs5">Galaxy s5</option>
                    <option value="g3" id="gs6">Galaxy s6</option>
                    <option value="g4" id="gs6e">Galaxy s6 Edge</option>
                    <option value="g5" id="gs6ep">Galaxy s6 Edge+</option>
                    <option value="g6" id="gs7">Galaxy s7</option>
                    <option value="g7" id="gs7e">Galaxy s7 Edge</option>
                    <option value="g8" id="gs8">Galaxy s8</option>
                    <option value="g9" id="gs8p">Galaxy s8+</option>  
                    <option value="g10" id="gs9">Galaxy s9</option>  
                    <option value="g11" id="gs9p">Galaxy s9+</option> 
                    <option value="g12" id="gso">Other</option>    
                </select>
            </div><br/>   <!-- Samsung S phones -->               
                <div class="form-group" id="sgnmodel">
                <b>What is the model of your phone?</b><br />
                <select class="form-control" name="sgnmodel" id="sgnmodel">">
                    <option value="sgn1" id="gn3">Galaxy Note 3</option>
                    <option value="sgn2" id="gn4">Galaxy Note 4</option>
                    <option value="sgn3" id="gne">Galaxy Note Edge</option>
                    <option value="sgn4" id="gn5">Galaxy Note 5</option>
                    <option value="sgn5" id="gn7">Galaxy Note 7</option>
                    <option value="sgn6" id="gnfe">Galaxy Note Fan Edition</option>
                    <option value="sgn7" id="gn8">Galaxy Note 8</option>
                    <option value="sgn8" id="gn9">Galaxy Note 9</option>
                    <option value="sgn9" id="gno">Other</option>    
                </select>
            </div><br/>  <!-- Samsung Note phones -->       
            <div class="form-group" id="nmodel">
                <b>What is the model of your phone?</b><br />
                <select class="form-control" name="nmodel" id="nmodel">">
                    <option value="nn1" id="n3">Nokia 3</option>
                    <option value="nn2" id="n5">Nokia 5</option>
                    <option value="nn3" id="n6">Nokia 6</option>
                    <option value="nn4" id="n8">Nokia 8</option>
                    <option value="nn5" id="n31">Nokia 3.1 2018 version</option>
                    <option value="nn6" id="n51">Nokia 5.1 2018 version</option>
                    <option value="nn7" id="n61">Nokia 6.1 2018 version</option>            
                    <option value="nn8" id="no">Other</option>                    
                </select>
            </div><br/>   <!-- Nokia phones --> 
            <div class="form-group" id="smodel"> 
                <b>What is the model of your phone?</b><br />
                <select class="form-control" name="smodel" id="smodel">">
                    <option value="x1" id="xz3">Xperia Z3</option>
                    <option value="x2" id="xz4">Xperia Z4</option>
                    <option value="x3" id="xz5">Xperia Z5</option>
                    <option value="x4" id="xx">Xperia X</option>
                    <option value="x5" id="xxa">Xperia XA</option>
                    <option value="x6" id="xxz">Xperia XZ</option>
                    <option value="x7" id="xxa1">Xperia XA1</option>
                    <option value="x8" id="xo">Other</option>                                       
                </select>
            </div><br/> <!-- Sony phones -->                     
             <div class="radio" id="turnon">
              <b>Does it still turn on?</b><br />
        <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="turnon" id="turnon_yes" value="t1">
                        Yup it turns on.
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="turnon" id="turnon_no" value="t0">
                        No it doesn't! 
                    </label>
      </div><br/> <!--if device can power on or not -->        
      <div class="radio" id="liquiddamage">
           <b>Has it been liquid damaged?</b><br />
        <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="liquiddamage" id="liquiddamage_yes" value="111">
                        Yup it went for a swim. 
                    </label>
          <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="liquiddamage" id="liquiddamage_no" value="110">
                        Nope. 
                    </label>
      </div><br/> <!-- if device's been liquid damaged  --> 
      <div class="form-group" id="problem">
                <b>General Services</b><br />
                <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="problem" id="problem" value="p1">
                        Screen Replacement (Original Quality)
                    </label><br/>
                <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="problem" id="problem" value="p2">
                        Screen Replacement (Aftermarket Quality)
                    </label><br/>
                <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="problem" id="problem" value="p3">
                        Battery Replacement
                    </label><br/>
                <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="problem" id="problem" value="p4">
                        Power Button Replacement
                    </label><br/>
                <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="problem" id="problem" value="p5">
                        Volume/Mute Button Replacement
                    </label><br/>
                <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="problem" id="problem" value="p6">
                        Loudspeaker Replacement
                    </label><br/>
                <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="problem" id="problem" value="p7">
                        Earpiece Replacement
                    </label><br/>
          
                <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="problem" id="problem" value="p8">
                        Microphone Replacement
                    </label><br/>
                <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="problem" id="problem" value="p9">
                        Charging Port Replacement
                    </label><br/>
                <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="problem" id="problem" value="p10">
                        Front Camera Replacement
                    </label><br/>
                <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="problem" id="problem" value="p11">
                        Rear Camera Replacement
                    </label><br/>
                <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="problem" id="problem" value="p12">
                        Proximity Sensor Replacement
                    </label><br/>
                <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="problem" id="problem" value="p13">
                        Home Button Replacement
                    </label><br/>
          
      </div><br/> <!-- list of repairs -->
                        
<div id="result">
     <b>So the estimated total cost is</b><br />
       <input type="text" id="finalpriceexcvat" />
    </div> <!--Total cost-->
    </div>
      </form>
```

Comment: you can use onchange event

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using a framework for this? Something like Angular or React? Even Knockout would be better for this.

Comment: You can not add `click event listener` for `option id`

Comment: Suggestion: why not leave the questions visible? Is it really a better experience if you hide them and implement ad hoc logic to show them? Alternatively, depending on what browsers you’re supporting, could you give each question a height of `100vh` and use [CSS snap points](https://css-tricks.com/introducing-css-scroll-snap-points/)? Then all you would have to do is change the target after each question.

Comment: Regarding the specific question, you can change the event to `change`, group your radio buttons into `fieldset`s instead of `div`s, and use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to avoid having to repeat your code: `$("#fieldset-id").on("change", "input", function (e) { /* show and hide */ });`

Comment: @WesleyCoetzee argh... yeh I was like i need jquery then click click and paste my codes ... D:

Comment: @Dr.Strange Damn... so that's why...

Comment: @Aankhen Well I thought the website would look cleaner if I hide and show the questions.  Especially with say just "Samsung Galaxy S models" by itself i've got like 11 options there, if i'm going to include "iPhone" "Sony" etc that'll be like.. 30 options? And then with the liquid damage question does it turn on etc, personally i'm just not a big fan of scrolling up and down when surfing a webpage.

Comment: @Aankhen Thanks for the suggestion. i've been repeating my codes as it seems "easier" to get it working and then work out a better solution..I know it does look like a cluster f#$k :P

Comment: @NikhilGhuse Hey thanks for getting me an alternative solution.. however that doesn't really answer my question of why the heck listener won't respond after selecting options... Until Dr.Strange pointed out it doesn't work with option id.

Answer (score -1):

( My english is not good. so forgive me if I did or write any horrible things )
Without using Id you can simplify this by using 'class'

```
<div class="form-group text-center">
      <b>Is it a tablet or a phone?</b><br />
      <div class="radio" id="phone">
        <label>
           <input type="radio" name="phone" id="phone_yes" value="1" class="phone_values">
               It's a tablet.
        </label>

      </div>
      <div class="radio">
        <label>
           <input type="radio" name="phone" id="phone_no" value="0" class="phone_values">
             It's a phone.
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Functions looks like :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   showProblem();
   hideBrand();
   hideProblem();
   hideIpmodel();
   hideStype();
   hideSgsmodel();
   hideSgnmodel();
   hideNmodel();
   hideSmodel();
   hideTurnon();
   hideLiquiddamage();


   var phone_values = document.getElementsByClassName( "phone_values" );

   for( var a = 0; a < phone_values.length; a++ ) {

      phone_values[a].addEventListener( "click", function() {

         showBrand(); //call the function you want to show next. 
                      //no need to call hide functions.

      }

   } 

} );
```

If you do something like this,

```
document.getElementById('gns').addEventListener('click', function() {
    showBrand();
    hideProblem();
    hideIpmodel();
    showStype(); //show
    hideSgsmodel();
    showSgnmodel();
    hideNmodel();
    hideSmodel();
    hideTurnon();
    hideLiquiddamage();
  });

  document.getElementById('nokiaphone').addEventListener('click', function() {
    showBrand();
    hideProblem();
    hideIpmodel();
    hideStype(); //hide*
    hideSgsmodel();
    hideSgnmodel();
    showNmodel();
    hideSmodel();
    hideTurnon();
    hideLiquiddamage();
  });
```

when you select 'gns', Types are starting to show. but whenever you select type it's hiding types by itself. because of that every time call only the function which you want to show.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. It does look a hell lot cleaner than mine.. So long story short, eventlistener won't work with option id, but will respond to values?

Comment: EventListeners are working for both Id and class, but if you're using Id you have to write eventListeners for each and every element. With `class` you can write one eventListener and loop it. 

And the other point is don't call 'hide' functions every time. Just call 'show' function.

Comment: Interesting.. Dananjaya is it possible for you to put that in JSFiddle? I can't seem to get anything to printout after getElementbyClassname. Thanks